Unable to get Bluetooth to Recognize Discoverable Devices
I recently bought a Geekom IT13 to run Elementary OS on.  When I got the mini-PC I installed xubuntu on it and with some work get everything working.  I then downloaded and installed Elementary OS 8.  It seemed like everything went fine until I tried to set up my bluetooth devices.  I opened the BT manager and tried to pair a speaker and my mouse.  It just spun searching for devices.
$ inxi --bluetooth
Bluetooth:
Device-1: IMC Networks Wireless_Device driver: btusb type: USB
Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
But when I issue the "bluetooth status" command I get:
gregh@IT13:~$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-12-02 21:32:23 UTC; 22min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 11093 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
Tasks: 1 (limit: 38059)
Memory: 784.0K (peak: 1.5M)
CPU: 34ms
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
└─11093 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
Dec 02 21:32:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
Dec 02 21:32:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
Dec 02 21:32:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Dec 02 21:47:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.267 tried to register 00001133-0000…gistered
Dec 02 21:47:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.267 tried to register 00001132-0000…gistered
Dec 02 21:47:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.267 tried to register 0000112f-0000…gistered
Dec 02 21:47:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.267 tried to register 00001104-0000…gistered
Dec 02 21:47:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.267 tried to register 00001106-0000…gistered
Dec 02 21:47:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.267 tried to register 00001105-0000…gistered
Dec 02 21:47:23 IT13 bluetoothd[11093]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.267 tried to register 00005005-0000…gistered
These seem to conflict with each other.  This is likely an OS configuration problem since I also installed xubuntu on my IT13 and it worked fine.

Try 'sudo rfkill unblock all" in Terminal

It seems like your Bluetooth service is active and running, but the issue might be related to the Bluetooth adapter not properly initializing or conflicting profiles, as you noticed from the logs.
Here are a few things to try:

Ensure Bluetooth is enabled:
The hciconfig output shows the state as "down," which means the Bluetooth interface might be off. You can try bringing it up manually with the following command:
sudo hciconfig hci0 up

Then, check again if it starts working with your Bluetooth devices.

Check if bluetoothd is properly handling profiles:
The logs show repeated attempts to register Bluetooth profiles. Some of these profiles might not be supported or could be conflicting. You can try disabling unnecessary Bluetooth profiles by editing the bluetoothd configuration file:
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

Look for the DisablePlugins setting and add or uncomment it with the profiles you don't need (e.g., DisablePlugins = rfcomm, obex, etc.).

Reinstall Bluetooth drivers and dependencies:
Since this works on Xubuntu, it might be worth reinstalling some packages that might not be fully configured for Elementary OS. Run:
sudo apt install --reinstall bluez bluez-tools pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth

Then, check the Bluetooth status again.

Check for conflicts:
If any other Bluetooth tools or services are running, they could conflict with bluetoothd. You can check if something like blueman is interfering:
ps aux | grep bluetooth

If you see multiple Bluetooth managers or services, you may want to disable or remove them.

Worked for me:
I had the same issue, but on another machine (Acer Aspire 3 laptop). I connected a random external USB bluetooth adapter, and then unplugged it. Since bluetooth wasn't failing any more.


Let me know if any of these steps help!
